# Calling sftp endpoint from java component

Tags: java, mule, sftp

I have a java component and would like to have it perform an sftp upload. I am looking at org.mule.transport.sftp for a way to directly instantiate a class for an "endpoint". I see I could use SftpClient but this does not look like the class that is used directly by the endpoint. Does anyone know what class would be best for me to perform such an sftp upload (Maybe SftpConnector.class?) I want to be able to set the properties myself, instead of relying on the limitations of the XML notation (my main goal is to have some logic to create the properties, such as identityFile, ...).

Thanks,

Comment: Looking at SftpConnector, it looks like it expects an endpoint. I'm wondering if I could create an ImmutableEndpoint from my java code, then pass this as part of the SftpConnectionFactory.class.
Would this be the Mule-ish way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mule-ish way to interact with transports is via the `MuleClient`.

Inject the `MuleContext` in your Java component, get the `MuleClient` from it and then use `send` or `dispatch` with a URI that matches the SFTP endpoint you want to interact with (like `sftp://...`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't think the identityFile path ever gets into the the sftp URI though, does it? -- Also, congratulations on the new edition of your book!

Comment: No, the `indentityFile` is configured on the SFTP connector, which you'll need to configure in XML. Thanks for the book, BTW using transports with the Mule client is explained in chapter 12.

Comment: Only issue is, I need to set the identityFile value at runtime from the payload (I write a string (RSA key) to a file, and then need to give the path as the identityFile value. It looks like identityFile only takes strings, not mule expressions. This is why I want to call the sftp transport/endpoint from a java component, because I need to somehow pass it a different identityFile path each time. From what I can tell, using XML won't allow me to do this. Thanks for the pointers on chapter 12!

Comment: Looking at the source code ( https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/transports/sftp/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/sftp/SftpUtil.java#L229 ) it seems that the `indentityFile` can be provided as an endpoint attribute. Therefore, it should be possible to pass it in the URI as a regular query parameter.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for your answer!